# Updating multiple columns of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I've two tables with the following fields:

table1 :  OTNAME
table2 :  SNCODE,     description_text

I'm trying to add the two columns of table2 to table1 and update the columns. My query is:

```
alter table  table1 add sncode integer                              
alter table  table1 add description_text varchar2(30)

update table1 set 
sncode,description_text = (SELECT  sncode, description_text
   FROM   table2, table1
  WHERE   SUBSTR (otname, INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                         + 1, 
                         INSTR (otname, '.', 1, 4)
                              - INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                              - 1)
                               = sncode)
```

I get an error: ORA 00927 - Missing Equal to Operator, pointing to the second line of my update statement. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Regards,

novice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MERGE
INTO    table1 t1
USING   table2 t2
ON      (SUBSTR (otname, INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                         + 1, 
                         INSTR (otname, '.', 1, 4)
                              - INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                              - 1)
                               = t2.sncode))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET    t1.sncode = t2.sncode,
       t1.description_text = t2.description_text
```

You also can simplify your expression:

```
MERGE
INTO    table1 t1
USING   table2 t2
ON      (REGEXP_SUBSTR(otname, '[^.]+', 1, 4) = t2.sncode)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET    t1.sncode = t2.sncode,
       t1.description_text = t2.description_text
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I get a MISSING ON KEYWORD error. Is your code targetted to oracle 10g ?

Comment: Could you please post your table definitions so that I could check the syntax?

Comment: Hi, Not sure what exactly you meant by definitions. I'm posting the tables data types for your reference.

Table 2: 
sncode           integer
description_text  varchar2(30)

Table 1: 
otname                         varchar2(100)

Comment: @novice: sorry, I didn't notice them first. I updated the post, try now.

Comment: Fantastic.. Thanks a ton ! Works fabulously!

Comment: Hello Quassnoi,

Can you briefly tell me how this line works :

(REGEXP_SUBSTR(otname, '[^.]+', 1, 4) = t2.sncode)

thanks!

Comment: It's a regular expression. It searches the string for the `4th` sequence consisting of everything but the periods.

Comment: `.` is "a period", `[^.]` is "everything but a period", `[^.]+` is "a longest possible sequence of everything that is not a period", `REGEXP_SUBSTR(otname, '[^.]+', 1, 4)` is "the `4th` longest possible sequence of everything that is not a period, starting from symbol `1`"

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are missing brackets around the fields to be updated. Try

```
update table1 set 
( sncode,description_text) = (SELECT  sncode, description_text
   FROM   table2, table1
  WHERE   SUBSTR (otname, INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                         + 1, 
                         INSTR (otname, '.', 1, 4)
                              - INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                              - 1)
                               = sncode)
```

Comment: Hi Nagul, the error I see is :

ORA-01427: Single-row subquery returns more than one row 

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: My apologies. I looked only at the syntax error in your query. What this query is trying to do is update sncode, description_text for *all* rows with 1 set of value returned from the select query. To update each with the constructed value from existing columns, use the update..set..from or merge into..using..on syntax suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Try UPDATE SET FROM construct instead.
Something like

```
update table1 
set  sncode = t1.sncode, description_text = t1.description_text 
from table2 as t2, table1 as t1
where SUBSTR (otname, INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                     + 1, 
                     INSTR (otname, '.', 1, 4)
                          - INSTR (otname,'.', 1, 3)
                          - 1)
                           = sncode)
```

Comment: No, it is about Oracle. It's not explicitly mentioned in the question, but it is tagged with oracle and oracle10g.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10g. I get an error saying : " SQL COMMAND NOT PROPERLY ENDED "

Comment: You seem to have an extra paranthesis after sncode? Run the command as `select t1.sncode, t1.description_text from table2..` to first understand what's wrong. Further break down the where clause and you'll eventually get to the bit that's wrong. i.e Try `select substr(...) from table2` and so on ..

Comment: `Oracle` does not support `UPDATE FROM`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should not be including `table1` in the `SELECT` query. Perhaps this statement will work:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET
       (sncode, description_text)
       =
       (
         SELECT table2.sncode, table2.description_text
           FROM table2
          WHERE SUBSTR(
                  table1.otname,
                  INSTR(table1.otname,'.', 1, 3) + 1, 
                  INSTR(table1.otname, '.', 1, 4) - INSTR (table1.otname,'.', 1, 3) - 1
                ) = table2.sncode
       )
```